# Where did the French National Constituent Assembly meet on August 4, 1789?

Tags: france, 18th-century, french-revolution

Where did the National Constituent Assembly decide to abolish feudalism?

I read that the National Constituent Assembly did not meet in a specific place. Therefore I want to know where they met in the night of August 4, 1789 when the decision to abolish feudalism was made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While investigating a different part of the French revolution, I came to the following conclusion:

Until October 6, 1789, the National Constituent Assembly met in the Hôtel des Menus Plaisirs, Versailles. October 6, 1789 and onwards, the National Constituent Assembly met in Salle du Manège,  Paris.

Therefore they met in the Hôtel des Menus Plaisirs on August 4, 1789.